# cordova open pdf - fileOpener2

Tags: javascript, cordova, pdf

I want to open a PDF file with fileOpener2

my config.xml looks like this:

```
<feature name="FileOpener2">
    <param name="android-package"
        value="io.github.pwlin.cordova.plugins.fileopener2.FileOpener2" />
</feature>
<feature name="File Opener2">
    <param name="id" value="cordova-plugin-file-opener2" />
</feature>
```

My HTML code:

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">

function callPDF() {
cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open('/sdcard/Download/bericht74.pdf', 'application/pdf');
}

</SCRIPT>
</head>
    <body>
 <a href="#" onClick="callPDF()">
<strong>open pdf</strong></a>
```

And Eclipse tells me:

```
10-19 10:16:02.111: I/chromium(17201): [INFO:CONSOLE(18)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (18)
```

How can I call the fileOpener2 plugin correctly?

Comment: do you have a link to the cordova.js on your index.html?

Comment: yeah, thats it! thx!!!