# How to insert fileopener plugin?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm following this post.
[cordova open pdf - fileOpener2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212042/cordova-open-pdf-fileopener2?lq=1)

The plug-in is correctly configured, but it is not working. I get the following exception:

> 10-27 08:05:38.380: W/System.err(2054):
>   java.net.MalformedURLException: No installed handlers for this URL
>   10-27 08:05:38.380: W/System.err(2054):   at
>   org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(FileUtils.java:626)
>   10-27 08:05:38.380: W/System.err(2054):   at
>   org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.access$400(FileUtils.java:52) 10-27
>   08:05:38.380: W/System.err(2054):     at
>   org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$14.run(FileUtils.java:385) 10-27
>   08:05:38.380: W/System.err(2054):     at
>   org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$25.run(FileUtils.java:551)

My project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e583djlhk0mm6sr/pdf.rar?dl=0

The relevant code is in FileOpenerPlugin.java

Comment: Stop saying "does not work". Say WHAT does not work.

Comment: Im having issues when adding the plugin in worklight

Comment: Refer to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326426/unable-to-open-a-pdf-file-locally-using-a-custom-cordova-apache-plugin?noredirect=1#comment54450591_33326426.. I tried to create a plugin i get same error.
How to integrate a plugin in worklight

Comment: Mention your Worklight version. Provide your failing project.

Comment: im using version 7.1.

Comment: Provide your 7.1 project

Comment: you can find the prject here.
http://mfpreader.comze.com/pdfreader.rar

Comment: @Idan Adar: any solution?

Comment: The link leads to 404

Comment: the project is till in upload in a rar file.everything is inside. u just need to import and run. :)

Comment: @IdanAdar: please find the full project @ https://www.dropbox.com/s/e583djlhk0mm6sr/pdf.rar?dl=0.
thank you

Comment: @Idan Adar: any idea??

Comment: I did not get to it. I have other things to do right now.

Comment: the project is already uploaded in a rar file.everything is inside. u just need to import and run. :)

Comment: @Idan Adar: whats the error please?

Comment: As I wrote: "I did not get to it. I have other things to do right now."

Comment: how to add a predefine cordova plugin in Mobilefirst platform.

Comment: Not possible. Worklight does not support Cordova plug-in (the only option is per the blog post)

Comment: the only way is to create a custom plugin like in this post. Why it does not work?

Comment: Because it's not supported in the product.

Comment: i just ran the code i dont any erro code, it still is not working

Comment: so there is no way to open a pdf, nor epub file in mfp?

Comment: You need to stop thinking about this in MFP context. You can always write a custom cordova plug-in to implement native code inside it to handle this; if it's not working in the native code, the problem is in the native code and not in MFP.

Comment: the native code cant have any error because it a from a plugin file opener

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at your provided project... it *seems* to be correctly configured. But... you have a function called "`openPDF()`", **but you're not calling it from anywhere in your code**.

Make use of your function, otherwise it'll just sit there and do nothing.

Comment: i tried: <a href="#" onclick="openPDF();">click here </a>
i get this error:
 Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Comment: No need for that. For testing purposes just put "openPDF()" in your wlCommonInit() function. I'm getting a different error than yours. That error means your plug-in implementation contains an error. From a working perspective the plug-in is correctly configured.

Comment: The error is: `10-27 08:05:38.380: W/System.err(2054): java.net.MalformedURLException: No installed handlers for this URL
10-27 08:05:38.380: W/System.err(2054):  at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(FileUtils.java:626)
10-27 08:05:38.380: W/System.err(2054):  at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.access$400(FileUtils.java:52)
10-27 08:05:38.380: W/System.err(2054):  at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$14.run(FileUtils.java:385)
10-27 08:05:38.380: W/System.err(2054):  at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$25.run(FileUtils.java:551)
`

Comment: we get the same error. i just summarised the error code