# Issue while adding a custom Apache Cordova plugin in a MobileFirst app

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a plugin `fileopener` and I want to add it into MobileFirst app but I'm having difficulties doing so.

Things I have tried and did not work:

- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/
- Unable to open a .pdf file locally using a custom cordova apache plugin
- created a plugin: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/adding-native-functionality/android-adding-native-functionality-hybrid-application-apache-cordova-plugin/

Does anyone know the real way to add a plugin in MobileFirst that really works?

Comment: You are not really saying what the issue is. You say It doesn't work but what is the error exactly? Also, what version are you using?

Comment: Here is the project:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qblz0uxlnrj2rng/AACFdx7Y0upIpSbT2l-CYaara?dl=0

Comment: Looks like M.kane is a fake user. That link points to a project given by another user. The exact same project. Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33340378/how-to-insert-fileopener-plugin-in-ibm-worklight

Comment: You need to be very careful right now buddy. Did you look at the implementation of this project? Did you notice that it's not actually doing anything? There is a function "openPDF" but you are not calling the function from anywhere, so it doesn't do anything...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the full file system path or URL of the PDF you want to open then you can use `InAppBrowser` to do that. For example:

```
var path = "file:// or http://"
window.open(path, "_blank", "location=yes,hidden=no,closebuttoncaption=Close");
```

Comment: i also tried this. It works only in IOS. It does not work in android

Comment: on android try with ```_system``` instead of ```_blank```, it should launch an intent to open the pdf on any app installed that handles pdfs